BS4 and requests only finding and scraping first listed item in dropdown list
I have a scraper that I have written to fetch some data from 2 different URLS. The only difference between the two pages is that one has a dropdown list of menus while the other does not. The scraper works for the first url in urls and fetches everything, but on the second url, it only fetches data from the first dropdown option. I thought I had catered for this but it is not working.
Here is my code:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import csv

urls = ['https://untappd.com/v/other-half-brewing-co/1360488',
        'https://untappd.com/v/beer-witch/10272294']



def get_menu_beers(soup):
    beers_all = soup.find_all('ul', {'class': 'menu-section-list'})
    
    # Open the CSV file in write mode
    with open('scraped.csv', mode='a', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        
        for beer_group in beers_all:
            beers = beer_group.find_all('li')
            for beer in beers:
                details = beer.find('div', {'class': 'beer-details'})
                a_href = details.find("a",{"class":"track-click"}).get("href")
                id_num = re.findall(r'\d+', a_href)
                beer_id = int(id_num[-1])
                name_ = details.find("a",{"class":"track-click"}).text
                rating_value = details.find('div', {'class': 'caps small'})['data-rating']
                
                
                writer.writerow([str(name_).strip().replace('\n', ' '), rating_value])

for url in urls:         
    response = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        try:
            try:
                select_options = soup.find_all('select', {'class':'menu-selector'})

                if (len(select_options) > 0 ):
                    options_list = select_options[0].find_all('option')
                    menu_ids =[]
                    for option in options_list:
                        menu_ids.append(int(option['value']))

                    menu_urls = []
                    for menu_id in menu_ids:
                        menu_url = str(url)+ '?menu_id=' + str(menu_id)
                        menu_urls.append(menu_url)

        
                    for url in menu_urls:
                        res = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
                        s = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
                        get_menu_beers(s)

                else:
                    get_menu_beers(soup)
            except:
                print("Failed HERE")
        except:
            print(f"Failed: {url}")

I thought this part of my code would find all the dropdown options, generate the urls for each and scrape them individually, but nothing is happening
if (len(select_options) > 0 ):
                        options_list = select_options[0].find_all('option')
                        menu_ids =[]
                        for option in options_list:
                            menu_ids.append(int(option['value']))
    
                        menu_urls = []
                        for menu_id in menu_ids:
                            menu_url = str(url)+ '?menu_id=' + str(menu_id)
                            menu_urls.append(menu_url)

It works for this url https://untappd.com/v/other-half-brewing-co/1360488 but not for this one https://untappd.com/v/beer-witch/10272294
Could anyone show me what I am doing wrong?

Use the different URL, such as

You can also use selenium or playwright to select each dropdown option.

I think I am though, if you look at the part of the code I highlighted, I am collecting all those menu ids and assigning them to menu_ids and then iteratively adding each of them to the base url to create menu_urls then scraping each of those. Not working though
